# Geonetwork and CSW records hierachy

Tags: geonetwork, csw

I am new to Geonetwork but my understanding is that after harvesting the Catalog has a set of (CSW) Records that remain 'flat' and there s no hierarchy.

In particular, i have a number of Products that belong to different Catalogs and i need to query the CSW endpoint and get back a number of Products that belong to Catalog 1.

How can i set their association?

Comment: What version of GeoNetwork are you using? How are you harvesting them?

Comment: After harvesting you don't have a set of CSW Records, you have a set of metadata records. CSW is just a mechanism to harvest/query/update a set of metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to check the OGC specification for the CSW protocol (version 2): http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat

Maybe you can query by creator, distributor or some other attribute that helps you distinguish between catalogs. Unless you are using a specific schema that stores the original catalog, there is no way to query for that attribute.